# It there have any way to create the DLL with a header file by using visual C#?

Tags: c#

I am doing mine FYP by using the

1. Visual C#
2. Agilent VEE

I am try to import the DLL file which created from C# into Agilent VEE but VEE required the header file and library file for the importing.

Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, there is no header file, this is different from C++! To use old C/C++ code, use [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot consume a c# dll in your C++ project and vice versa (normally). You should either create a com aware dll in C# to consume it in C++ or on the other hand, you need to declare all the functions in C# to use from a c++ dll.

Here I am talking about standard dlls (not activex or com all). They require a different methodology to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can avoid the "Import Library" primitive in VEE, and not need a header file.

Use Device --> .NET Assembly References... and browse to your DLL files. Then you have to import or select a namespace. Finally, functions of the DLL appear in the function browser of VEE.

Not all DLL files can be used. I have two similar from a hardware vendor. The one named somename_net.dll works.

If you find an answer to your original question, I'd like to know. My method